# Excel objects disappear during query

Tags: excel, data-connections, vba

I have an Excel VBA-enabled workbook that has data connections which automatically refresh when the cells containing their parameters are updated.

Whenever one of those updates occurs, while the connection query is running, all objects on the worksheet disappear and do not reappear until the query has completed.  Regular cells and their contents remain, but charts and other shapes vanish.

While I'm not necessarily averse to this happening since the user really can't use the dashboards while the query is running anyway, the users don't like this and want the objects not to disappear.

Has anyone else encountered this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your refreshable data are contained within queryTable object you could use BeforeRefresh and AfterRefresh events to turn Application.ScreenUpdating on/off.
Maybe this will help.
It may also depend on BackgroundQuery property (QueryTable or PivotCache object if you are using pivot tables).